# QGIS - control of expansion and rotation of multiple Map-Windows in Layout

Tags: qgis, layouts

I created a polygon layer ('Blattschnitt') with two sections of a route of interest, with a certain expansion and rotation. The rotation has been calculated, if needed.

[image: model]

[image: attributes of 'Blattschnitt'-Layer]

In the Layout I set up two Map-Windows (f.e. Map1 & Map2) wich I would like to link to the sections from the layer 'Blattschnitt'. Is there a possibility? I assume the Atlas function does not apply with two Maps in one layout?

[image: Layout]

Answer (score 5):

You can use an expression in the data defined override of the map rotation in each map to reference the `"rotate"` attribute in the `Blattschnitt` layer.

[image]

For example, for the rotation of `'Map 1'`:

Either get the feature using the `Blatt nr` attribute:

```
attribute(
    get_feature(
        layer:='Blattschnitt',
        attribute:='Blatt nr',
        value:='Blatt 1'
    ), 
    'rotate'
)
```

Or simply by the feature id:

```
attribute(
    get_feature_by_id(
        layer:='Blattschnitt',
        feature_id:=1
    ),
    'rotate'
)
```

Both of these expressions will return `-51,262`. Use the expression again for `'Map 2'` but alter the `Blatt nr` attribute value, or `feature_id` accordingly.

###### A dynamic solution

Alternatively, in the following example on my layer called `sections`, I use the `main_angle` function on the polygons to get the rotation angle dynamically. The `section` number is referenced automatically by substringing the `Map` id (in my case, the 5th character of the id is the number following `Map`). In this case, the same expression can be used on each map, provided the map id number matches the `section` number - no need to change anything.

[image]

```sql
with_variable('angle',
    main_angle(
        geometry(
            get_feature('sections', 'section', 'section ' || substr(@map_id, 5, 5))
        )
    ),
    
    case 
        when @angle >= 90 and @angle < 180
        then -@angle + 90
        when @angle >= 0 and @angle < 90
        then 90 - @angle
    end
)
```

[image]

Comment: wow, that dynamic function looks swsome. i hope i can reproduce the steps... :) Thank you very much so far. 

Can you tell me also how to set the extent of the maps to the extent of the geometries? In fact i have created the geometries by using the tool 'Create Layer from extent'...

Answer (score 3):

To have both the `Rotation` and the `Extent` adapt automatically, you need to do the following:

- apply the geometry rotation to the `Map item Rotation` (via the `rotation` field or the `main_angle`). You might want to use `main_angle` as it will ensure better consistency when the angle changes from quadrant to quadrant
- set the `Map item Extents` based on the polygon geometry, and there's a trick as the polygon geometry (Xmin/Xmax/Ymin/Ymax don't work)

In my example, the layer containing the reference polygons is called `ref`, and polygons have an `id` field.

Set the `Map item Rotation` to :

`90-main_angle(geometry(get_feature('ref','id',1)))` where `1` is the id of the polygon you refer to in this case

Set the `Map item Extents` to:

Xmin field formula:

```
x_min(
       rotate(
              geometry(get_feature('ref','id',1)),
              90-main_angle(geometry(get_feature('ref','id',1)))))
```

Apply the same formula for Xmax, Ymin, Ymax, replacing the first x_min(...) by x_max(...) and so on.

Replace the id number according to the targeted polygon (or use the suggested dynamic index)

Xmin setup for Map2 / polygin id = 2:
[image]

### Example 1:

[image]

[image]

### Example 2:

[image]

[image]

---

The key part for the Extents is to rotate the polygon `$geometry` before extracting the min/max extents.
If you just take the extent of the geometry itself, you don't get a suitable result:

[image]